# I want to know good syntax for mysql pdo json

Tags: mysql, json, pdo

I haven't found the good syntax to update my table on `mysql` using `json_set`.

Would you give me some help? I want to update and know the good syntax for this query.

```
public function mkjson()
{
    $friends = '"pachou", "eric", "francis"';
    $tagfriendsjson = json_encode($friends);

    try
    {
        include('connect.ini');
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    $ver = 'SELECT * FROM tagusers WHERE tag_users_id="'.$_SESSION['tagusersid'].'"';
    $ask = $bdd->query($ver);
    $ans = $ask->fetch();

    if (empty($ans['tag_friends']))
    {
        $req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE tagusers SET = {"1": "pachou", "2": "eric", "3":  "francis", "4": "Henry"} WHERE tag_users_id="'.$_SESSION['tagusersid'].'" ');
        $req->execute();
    }
    else
    {

    }
    return true;
}
```

: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= {"4": "Henry"} WHERE tag_users_id="2"' at line 1 in /var/www/tagmeyou.com/php/class.Friendlist.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/tagmeyou.com/php/class.Friendlist.php(34): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /var/www/tagmeyou.com/fr/vues/body/inputtag.php(23): Friendlist->mkjson() #2 /var/www/tagmeyou.com/fr/vues/body/bodytagscreen.php(10): include('/var/www/tagmey...') #3 /var/www/tagmeyou.com/fr/vues/tagscreen.php(34): include('/var/www/tagmey...') #4 {main} thrown in

Comment: I really recommend not using json as a field value, it's so messy :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in this query:

```
UPDATE tagusers SET = {"1": "pachou", "2": "eric", "3":  "francis", "4": "Henry"} WHERE tag_users_id="'.$_SESSION['tagusersid'].'"
```

Firstly, there is no column name being set (between `SET` and `=`). Secondly the JSON should be in single quotes. Try changing that line to

```
    $req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE tagusers SET colname = \'"1": "pachou", "2": "eric", "3":  "francis", "4": "Henry"}\' WHERE tag_users_id="'.$_SESSION['tagusersid'].'" ');
```

Where `colname` is the column you want to store the JSON in.

Comment: If it solved your problem it would be good if you could mark it accepted so that other users searching for this question can find it.